# undefined method for #<Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this inside `User` model

```
def self.home_opinions (user) 
        home_opinions = user.opinions
        user.follows.find_each do |follow|
          home_opinions+=(follow.opinions)
        end
        home_opinions.order_by_most_recent
    end
```

I have this scope inside `Opinion` model

```
scope :order_by_most_recent, -> { includes(:author).order(created_at: :desc) }
```

It shows this error

```
undefined method `order_by_most_recent' for #<Array:0x00007eff64d076f8>
```

But when I try `User.home_opinions(User.find(9))` inside rails console
It works

I have two questions

1. why It shows the error
2. What are the best practices for this code maybe using `includes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.order_by_most_recent` will only work on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

When you call `home_opinions = user.opinions` you get a relation object back.

The problem comes when you call

```
home_opinions += follow.opinions
```

That action converts the relation into an array, and then `.order_by_most_recent` is no longer available.

If you can, you should try and get all relevant opinions in a single ActiveRecord call. That way, you'll have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which you can chain with other scopes – plus, you can do everything in a fixed number of database calls, rather than an extra call for every member of the `follows` association.

Try something like:

```rb
opinion_owner_ids = [user.id] + user.follow_ids
home_opinions = Opinion.where(user_id: opinion_owner_ids)
home_opinions.order_by_most_recent
```

Comment: `def self.home_opinions (user)`
    `follows_ids = []`
    `user.follows.find_each do |follow|`
      `follows_ids.push(follow.id)`
    `end`
   ` ids = [user.id] + [follows_ids]`
   ` home_opinions = Opinion.where(author_id: ids)`
    `home_opinions.order_by_most_recent`
 ` end`

I did that and works thank you!

Comment: Btw how to add multiple line code in a comment in stack overflow :D?

Comment: You shouldn't need to construct your own array of IDs by looping through `user.follows`. If you've declared `has_many :follows` in your `User` model, you will automatically get a method called `follow_ids` that includes all the ID records. Have a look at the **Example** section in the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Comment: Yes I did that and its working thanks again
    `ids =  [user.id] + user.follow_ids`
    `home_opinions = Opinion.where(author_id: ids)`
    `home_opinions.order_by_most_recent`